# Can't set environment variables at my bashrc file (Permission Denied)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, pip

I was trying to set some environment variables requested by python on my macOS 10.14.6, however when I look up to my bashrc file at `/etc/` I can't do anything (`nano ~/.bashrc`) since I only have permission to read the file. A thing that makes me wondering is that this file is named as bashrc instead of .bashrc, same thing to my bash_profile.

Hope you can help me, I've been searching answers for a long time, however didn't find one that works for me.

Comment: Have you tried tried `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` instead of just `nano ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: an aside, make sure your terminal is using `bash`. MacOS now uses `zshrc` as the default shell. you can check your current shell with `echo $0` in an interactive terminal session. **IF** you are using `zsh`, modify the zprofile file as required. if you want to **change** your shell to `bash`, use `chsh -s bash <username>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 files:

- `/etc/bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc`) owned by root,
- `$HOME/.bashrc` owned by the user.

Each time an interactive bash is run, bash reads `/etc/bashrc` then `$HOME/.bashrc`.

If you want to set some environment variables for your user, the best place is probably `$HOME/.bashrc`.

You may also prefer `$HOME/.profile` which is read at login time and available also for non interactive bash, e.g. when running bash
scripts.

For a complete description, see [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)